# Swap SQL primary keys without affecting auto increment?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have a table storing basic article information:

**table name: cms_articles**

```
[article_id] , [article_header] , [article_content]
     1 , test , test content
     2 , another , something
     3 , article , text
```

I am using the following SQL to swap the article ID's of two articles:-

```
"UPDATE cms_articles SET article_id=99999 WHERE article_id=".$article_id1
"UPDATE cms_articles SET article_id=".$article_id1." WHERE article_id=".$article_id2
"UPDATE cms_articles SET article_id=".$article_id2." WHERE article_id=99999"
```

So I am simply swapping their ID's while using a temporary ID of 99999 while the swap occurs.

This works, but then when I add a new article to the table it sets the ID to 100000 automatically thanks to the `autoincrement`, despite the highest article_id actually being 3!

Comment: What business reason fo you have for needing to swap ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute the alter table statement and set the auto_increment value

```
$sql = "ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE AUTO_INCREMENT = 3";
```

Answer (score 2):

To what effect are you swapping primary keys?
No wait it doesn't matter.

As SQL is a declarative programming language and not a procedural one.
Swapping a 'primary key' is wrong and correcting you here will insure an innocent passerby doesn't adopt your laissez-faire to good design principles.

Answer (score 1):

First get current autoincrement value with these query:

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name = 'table_name'
AND table_schema = DATABASE( ) ;
```

Then make your id swap. And then set autoincrement value back to its previous value like @DevZer0 wrote:

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE AUTO_INCREMENT = $previous_value
```